# Java dependent object serialization consistency

Tags: java, serialization

I have Employee containing Address and both are serializable.But when I do serialization test it fails I see that address have diffrent Id

Serialized:Address@6adca536 Deserialized: Address@6b143ee9
I am not sure if I need to implement my own serialization.

```
public class EmployeeTestU extends BaseUnitTest {

    private Employee employee;
    private Address address

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName("Foo:);
        employee.setId(1l);
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setPincode("23433");
        address.setArea("testArea");
        List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
        addressList.add(address);
        employee.setAddress(addressList);
    }




    @Test
    public void testConsistency() throws IOException, CloneNotSupportedException, ClassNotFoundException{
        byte[] serialized1 = serialize(employee);
        byte[] serialized2 = serialize(employee);

        Object deserialized1 = deserialize(serialized1);
        Assert.assertEquals(employee, deserialized1);
    }

public class Employee implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5991582870430548008L;

        private Long id;

        private List<Address> addresses;

        private String  name;

        public Employee() {
        }
        //getter setter and default consutructor

    }

public class Address implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5991582870430548008L;
    private String pincode;

    private String area;
    private String state;
    //getter setter and default consutructor

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

So you have two different objects (by different I mean that they are located in different places in memory) that is why your default implementation for `hashCode()` returns different values. You could check values of the properties between initial and restored objects to see that they are the same.

To be able to use `Assert.assertEquals()` you need to override `equals()` in your class (and it's better to override `hashCode()` when you override `equals()`)

Comment: Thats perfect I got to know I was not implementing equals hashcode

Answer (score 1):

`Assert.assertEquals(Object, Object)` uses the `Object.equals` method to test the equality.

Your serialization is working. What does not is your asumption about the default `Object.equals` method.

Default `Object.equals` will compare the reference of your objects, not the state of your objects. And since deserialization is effectively the construction of an object, the following...

```
byte[] serialized1 = serialize(employee);
Object deserialized1 = deserialize(serialized1);
```

... creates a new object. `deserialized1` is not `employee`: it is a newly created object through deserialization. This new object has another reference, and the test fails.

Override and implement `Object.equals` and `Object.hashCode` as suggested by @Ivan.